# I need help with continuity and intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The problem says:

> The roots of $f(x)=x^3-2x-x^2+2$ are $\sqrt{2}$, $-\sqrt{2}$, and $1$. By evaluating $f(-3)$, $f(0)$, $f(1.3)$, and $f(2)$, determine the sign of $f(x)$ on each of the intervals between its roots.

I'm struggling with this subject. It may sound like a stupid excuse but the the book doesn't explain well enough sometimes, I was asked on an exercise to use the method of bisection (which I didn't understand as well as I'd like) and it didn't even mention $\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}$. I had to find that on the internet. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I'd suggest by starting with drawing the graph of any function that cross the $x$-axis three times. Since it only intersects the $x$-axis three times, that means in between those zeroes, the sign (positive or negative) must be constant.

Answer (score 2):

Most people get introduced to the notion of continuity first by the statement "You can draw the graph without lifting pencil off the page". Of course, this bears little resemblance to the limit definition; what they're obliquely referring to is the intermediate value theorem.

Basically it says, if you're drawing the graph of a function, and this graph appears **above** a horizontal line somewhere, and **below** the horizontal line somewhere else, then somewhere in between, it has to **cross** the horizontal line.

In this case, we can use it to see that, between its roots, a continuous function has to stay **above** or **below** the $x$-axis, but never change between. Why? Because otherwise the function must cross the $x$-axis (i.e. have a root) between the two roots, which is against assumption.

So, if we look at one point between consecutive roots of a continuous function, its sign (i.e. whether it's positive or negative) will be the same sign as **every** point on the interval of points between those consecutive roots.

Answer (score 1):

For large $x$ the sign of the polynomial is same as that of $x$ and hence $f(x) >0$ in $(\sqrt{2},\infty)$ and $f(x) <0$ in $(-\infty, - \sqrt{2})$. Next $f(x) $ has same sign as that of $f(0)$ in $(-\sqrt{2},1)$ ie $f(x) >0$ in this interval. The sign of $f(x) $ in interval $(1,\sqrt{2})$ can be found out more easily by using value of derivative $f'(1)=-1$. Clearly $f$ is decreasing at $1$ and hence $f(x) <0$ in $(1,\sqrt{2})$. This is somewhat simpler than using the value of $f(1.3)$ which is difficult to evaluate.

The key here is the intermediate value theorem which implies that between any two consecutive roots the sign of the function remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Since f(x) is a cubic polynomial, it is continuous and it has at most 3 real roots. This comes from the fundamental theorem of algebra.

As, it is given that there are 3 real roots, there are exactly 3 roots, and it is not possible for the curve to cross the x-axis between $-\sqrt 2$ and $1$

So, if we examine $f(x)$ at any $x$ in the interval $(-\sqrt 2, 1), f(x)$ must be on that side of $0$ for all $x$ in the interval.  $x = 0$ is inside the interval and $f(0) = 2$ so $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (-\sqrt 2, 1).$  Use this logic to evaluate the other intervals. $(-\infty, -\sqrt 2),(1,\sqrt 2)$ and $(\sqrt 2, \infty)$